# Statistics (unsure how to do it)

Tags: statistics

A person's resting heart rate is the lowest number of heart beats per minute when fully relaxed and without distractions. Age, fitness, genetics, health status and gender affect the resting heart rate. Suppose that for a certain population of adults, the resting heart rate is normally distributed, with a mean of 70bpm and a standard deviation of 5 bpm.

A) Approximately 68% of this population have their resting heart rate between which two values?

So for this I did 
(0.68x5)+70=
73.4

Which means the 2 values would be??

B) What percentage of adults in this population have a resting heart rate between 75 and 80 bpm

For this I did
(77.5-70)/5 
= 1.5 which I think is vey wrong

C) if the resting heart rates were measured for 250 adults in this population, how many of them would be expected to have a resting heart rate below 65 bpm

Idk how to do this one

Comment: hint for A): 68% of the distribution will fall within one standard deviation of the mean.

Comment: Welcome to the site. For homework problems, you should show something of your own thinking along with the question.

Answer (score 1):

(A) Let Z be standard normal and X be the resting heart rate, then
P(Z > (x-70)/5) = 1 - (68%/2) = 0.16

Note that standard normal is symmetric. So if you have a z table that z value at upper tail (or use Excel or calculator), you will find that this z value is 0.9944578832

Thus,

(x-70)/5 = 0.9944578832
=> x = 74.97228942 is the higher value

By symmetry of standard normal, and P(Z < (x-70)/5) = 1 - (68%/2) = 0.16, the z value for the lower tail is -0.9944578832. Thus

(x-70)/5 = -0.9944578832
=> x = 65.02771058 is the lower value

Answer (score 0):

(B) P(75 < X < 80) = P(X < 80) - P(X < 75)
    = P(Z < (80 - 70)/5) - P(Z < (75 -70)/5)
    = 0.9772498681 - 0.8413447461
    = 0.135905122

Answer (score 0):

(C) P(X < 65) = P(Z < (65 - 70)/5) = 0.1586552539
    Given sample of 250 adults, the no of adults expected to have resting heart
    rate below 65 bpm is
    250 * 0.1586552539
    = 40    (round up from 39.66381348)

Comment: There are many answers (one symmetrical one). You have given 'half' of one of them. Also, it is customary to give all one's answers together in one Answer box.

Comment: Thanks Bruce for your comment. I am new to this site and still figuring out how it works. I will put all answers in one Answer box in future